# how to display more than one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have got a problem with my script, I'm still trying to find out how to display more than one array, I can only display no more than one array.

Here is the output:

```
20140426100000
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "10:00 AM",
    "11:00 AM",
    "12:00 PM",
    "12:30 PM",
    "2:00 PM",
    "2:30 PM",
    "9:00 PM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "12:00 AM",
    "12:30 AM",
    "1:00 AM",
    "1:30 AM",
    "2:00 AM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "12:00 AM",
    "12:30 AM",
    "1:00 AM",
);

// Save the output format
$DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

// function to get the state
function getState($string){
    $ex = explode(" ",$string);
    return $ex[1];
}

// GET the current STAGE
$current_state = getState($array[0]);
$offset = 0;

foreach($array as $time){

    // Get the item state.  
    $this_state = getState($time);

    // check if we past a day? 
    if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM"){
        $offset++;
    }
$this_unix = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
echo date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);
    echo "<br></br";

    $current_state = $this_state;
}
?>
```

Can you please tell me how to display more than one array which it would display like this?

```
20140426100000
20140426110000
20140426120000
20140426123000
20140426140000
20140426143000
20140426210000
20140426230000
20140427000000
20140427003000
20140427010000
20140427013000
20140427020000
20140427110000
20140427120000
20140427123000
20140427130000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code works fine.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iWFY8H) Your error is an HTML one. You're missing the closing bracket on one of your `<br>` tags. This causes you to not see the output on your page.

```
echo "<br></br"; <-- HERE
```

Comment: What do you mean by "show one format in the output"? This solves the problem you have in your question.

Comment: Oh thank you john, sorry i have missed the `>` at the end. Can I ask you a question to see if you could help me with the arrays to make it get separate?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a fresh question so everyone can help you. I may have to walk away from my computer at any minute and I'd hate to leave you hanging.

Comment: how do you get these format separate when parsing the list of strings so I can input them in the xml start="" and end=""?